# Execute command in remote server using resources in client (linux)

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to execute command in a remote server using resoures in client (both sides are linux), ex: in client I have a shell file(ex: /home/john/helloworld.sh), I connect to a remote server using ssh, then I want to run this shell file in remote server without uploading it to this server

anyone have any solution for this problem?

edit: thanhk sehe, now I can run shell file from client, but I want to run a c program, any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh user@remote sh - < mylocalscript.sh
```

Test it directly on  your machine:

```
echo ls | ssh localhost sh -
```

**UPDATE**

To the comment: a trick sometimes employed by distro-agnostic deployment scripts is to embed a static, standalone image (make sure the kernel is compatible):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf8a0d6dfc58a719)**

The base64 data there was generated by doing

```
gcc -static -static-libgcc -Os -g0 -x c - <<< 'int main() {puts("hello world");return 0;}' -o standalone
dd if=standalone | gzip | base64 -w240
```

Comment: thanks, so how can I run a C program, I try "ssh user@remote ./ - <hello" (hello is complied file of hello.c) but it didn't work

Comment: You can't. You could do tricks with statically linked (standalone) applications. E.g.: (see edit coming in a minute)

Comment: 'ssh user@remote sh - < mylocalscript.sh `
If I use this command in client, can server save the log of commands in mylocalscript.sh? Because security reason, I dont' want server side know the commands in mylocalscript.sh

Comment: @spectre It's starting to look you're (a) out of your depth and (b) in the wrong forum. Everything is reverse engineerable. Everything can be logged (think virtualization). If you're a pentester, get the chops from your "guild master", if you're not, stop being evil.

Comment: LOL, you don't know my business

Comment: @spectre I don't indeed. But trying to hide your footsteps is dubious ethics no matter what business. Note how I expressly did *not* accuse/judge. But I do think you ought to have convincing arguments to enlist help achieving this dubious goal. The fact that you apparently cannot reach the basic conclusions on your own (you can't reliably erase your tracks) tells me that you're likely not in the kind of business that requires this for legitimate reasons. Just my hunch.

Comment: I build some things(heavy workload) for my partner, I don't have enough physical resources so they provide me a server, but I don't want they know how I do it(some secret information), nothing is dubious ethics here. Anyway, thank for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one and using scp to copy the file would be the most obvious solution. However depending on the access level you have on the remote server, you could look at [SSHFS (Wikipedia link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) which will allow you to mount the filesystem with the script in it.

Comment: Thanks, but this's not what I want, I don't want server side can access my resources